# crossfilter.js - Histogram with custom reduce function fails in filtering data

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

following situation: I have two plots, one scatterplot and one histogram for the x-values in this scatterplot. I wrote a custom reduce function that looks similar to this:

```
       let grouping = this._cf_dimensions[attribute].group().reduce(
        function(elements, item) {
           elements.items.push(item);
           elements.count++;

           return elements;
        },
        function(elements, item) {
                // console.log("item.id = " + item.id);
                let match = false;
                let values = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < elements.items.length && !match; i++) {
                    // Compare hyperparameter signature.
                    if (item.id === elements.items[i].id) {
                        match = true;
                        elements.items.splice(i, 1);
                        elements.count--;
                    }
                }
            }

            return elements;
        },
        function() {
            return {items: [], count: 0};
        }
    );
```

The problem: When I select points in my scatterplot, the correlating histogram does not update properly. I traced it back to the remove function, i. e. the second of the three functions above, being called for only *one* of my five groups (I checked by comparison of the length of `elements` with the original group size). That means that the `item`s to be removed won't be necessarily found.
In other words, the scatterplot selects the correct set of datapoints, but the remove function in the barchart grouping shown above, while registering the incoming filter update, is not called for all groups of this grouping (equivalently: not called for all bars in the bar chart).

I'm a bit at a loss, since I seem to remember successfully implementing dashboards with dc.js and crossfilter.js and the past exactly like this. Do I misunderstand something about the custom reduce concept or is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share a bit more about how you use this group. Preferably a working example that someone could run to see the problem actually happen. I don’t see anything wrong with this ground definition, so I would guess that there is a problem with dimension keys not being naturally ordered or something similar.

Comment: I would expect the remove function to be called only for the bin where the item resides, not all five bins. Like @EthanJewett says, if it's being called for the wrong bin and the item is not there, maybe there is a problem with inconsistent or poorly-ordered keys.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming there were items being removed in all bins/groups. Yeah, as @Gordon says, if the items being removed in the filter operation are only in one group, then it's only going to get called for that group.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll produce a working example as soon as possible. It's a bit tricky since I have to pluck it out from several places in a bigger application.
Regarding the filter/group: That's exactly the problem. The remove function gets called - for one particular group/bin - but the item to remove is not contained in that bin.

Comment: If a reproducible example is too difficult, it might be enough to show your dimension/group functions and a sample of your data, since it sounds like the problem is the key functions.

Comment: After almost two full days of digging into my code, I finally found the culprit: I copied a group's .all() return value. Since I wanted to analyze some of the data, I sorted it - the problem being that it was a shallow copy, not a deep one. So I sorted the original group data, which made the bin association mechanism go haywire. You were right, Gordon - the sorting was kind of the problem. Thanks to both you and Ethan!
I'd close the question myself, but apparently I don't have a high enough reputation.